# How to generate APK using command line/code for Cordova Project?

Tags: android, node.js, eclipse, cordova

I want to build and generate APK for Cordova project using command line/code, not using Eclipse or Android studio. Can anybody help me out on generating apk using command line/code?

I have tried the following ways but not able to succeed.

#### 1. APK Generate :

In my project, I went to the given path `D:\ProjectName\platforms\android\cordova` and ran `build.bat` file. Usually in my older projects it'll generate APK. But here I'm getting the following error.

```
Total time: 27.008 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\ProjectName\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\ProjectName\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

For fixing this issue, I upgraded gradle, which leads to deletion of code in my project.

#### 2. APK Generate:

I tried to build my project using command in node.js command prompt
Command : `Cordova build android`
but I got the following error.

Error details:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\init-package-json\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:9
    const syntaxErr = e.message.match(/^Unexpected token.*position\s+(\d+)/i)
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\init-package-json\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:12:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Please can anybody suggest any other way to generate APK using command line or code, because I tried way 1 in my older projects and it's working. Main issue I am facing is that in node.js command line I am not able to build my project.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161533/discussion-on-question-by-sangeeta-bhatt-how-to-generate-apk-using-command-line).